# Debugging spring-boot app in docker doesn't work

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, remote-debugging

I have a Spring Boot app running in a docker container that's setup using a Dockerfile and then a docker-compose.yml file. I recently added in the Java command `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=5050,server=y,suspend=n` into the Dockerfile to enable debugging. I have exposed the port 5050 and also mapped it in the docker-compose file. 
When I run the app on the container I start debugging through IntelliJ and it connects but if I set a breakpoint, it is never hit. Now I am not sure what I am doing wrong here as the remote debugger is connecting. I even tried changing the setting `suspend=y` and that worked i.e. the server wouldn't start until I started the debugger.

Here's the relevant work I have done;

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:8-alpine
WORKDIR /
EXPOSE 8000 5050
COPY target /
CMD java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=5050,server=y,suspend=n -jar /target/blockchain*.jar
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
multichain-api:
  build:
    context: ./blockchain
  networks:
    - multichain-network
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
    - "5050:5050"
  volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: ${PWD}/blockchain/target
      target: /target
  container_name: multichain-api
```

Any ideas on where I am gone wrong?

Comment: This question and the answer to it really helped me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You may need to add 0.0.0.0 or * to the address argument

- address=0.0.0.0:5050
- address=*:5050

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm with the "ps" command that there is a single instance of the process running within the container, and that it has the debug parameters applied?

I have been struggling with the exact same issue while trying to set up debugging with Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) within Docker. AEM automatically forks the process if there isn't enough memory available, but doesn't apply the debug parameters to the new process.

In this case the solution was to apply "-forkargs" parameters so that the debug configuration was passed to the forked process. Having done this the break points are now suspending the threads correctly.

This solution almost certainly won't work in your case but you could verify if it's a similar issue by checking if the process is forking without the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The config looks fine to me. If the debugger connects correctly, then please check if your breakpoints are enabled in IntelliJ. 
I assume that the issue is located within IntelliJ and not your docker config.

Could you provide the run config if it's still not working?

Comment: I checked and the breakpoints are enabled. And what do you mean by the run config? I just run the docker-compose.yml to create the containers and `mvn clean install` to create the jar

Comment: You can find the "run configuration" in IntelliJ under "Run" -> "Edit Configuration". There you should have an entry for remote debugging. The config should point to localhost:5050

Comment: Ah yes I get you now. So there's `Debugger mode: Attach to remote JVM`, `Host: localhost`, `Port: 5050` and `Command line arguments for remote JVM: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5050`

Comment: Well the good news: this seems to be alright. The bad news: this doesn't fix your issue.

Comment: haha, yea Im pretty confused by it as I can setup and execute remote debugging on my work machine, but not on my own

Comment: Is your application working correct, in other words: can you reach/trigger the process you try to debug? Is your spring boot app running on 8000 and respond accorrdingly?

Comment: Thats the thing, its working fine. I have a frontend on another container that calls my spring backend on port 8000, executes the commands and responds. So I put the breakpoints right at the start of the called methods so I know they would be definitely hit. When I make the call on the frontend, it updates with the response received but its like the breakpoints just aren't hit

Comment: Okay, I got one last idea. Instead of using the frontend is it possible to use a rest client like postman(https://www.getpostman.com/) and execute those command manually and check if the service works as expected.

Comment: I decided to test this one last time before I tried your suggestion and for some reason it now works, I have no idea why or whats different

Comment: Would be interesting to know what the issue was, but at least your issue is solved.

Comment: I was going back over it last night and did make one change. I had docker exposing port 8000 for the api calls, but spring was set to the default 8080. Now I don't/didn't think that would have solved the issue but it was the only thing I changed in my code i.e. updating the exposed port from 8000 to 8080